# MySQL max and count aggregate functions

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

So I have three tables

```
CREATE TABLE Personnel(
    IdPersonnel INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Name        VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    Surename    VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    Department  VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    Salary      INT NOT NULL,
    Birthday    DATE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Doctor(
    IdDoctor     INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    fk_Personnel INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Visit(
    IdVisit     INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Date        DATE NOT NULL,
    ControlDate DATE,
    fk_Patient  INT NOT NULL,
    fk_Doctor   INT NOT NULL,
);
```

From these three tables, I need to get a doctor who had most of the visits.

```
SELECT p.Name, p.Surname, COUNT(*) visits
  FROM Visit v
  JOIN Doctor d
    ON v.fk_Doctor = d.IdDoctor
  JOIN Personnel p
    ON d.fk_Personnel = p.IdPersonnel
 GROUP BY d.IdDoctor
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
 LIMIT 1;
```

I used this query, and the result is correct, but I have to use MAX() function. I am using MySQL Community server 8.0.26

Comment: Why do you *have to use MAX()*?

Comment: Why do you need to join the personnel table, what is "z.fk_osebje" in your query?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select P.Name, P.Surename, P.IdPersonnel ,count(*) from Visit V
inner join Doctor D on V.fk_Doctor = D.IdDoctor
inner join Personnel P on D.fk_Personnel = P.IdPersonnel
group by P.Name, P.Surename, P.IdPersonnel
having count(*) = (
select max(visits) from
(select fk_Doctor, count(*) visits from Visit group by fk_Doctor) a
)
```

Comment: The problem your answer only gives me doctor's id but not his name. You left out the Personnel table

Comment: I've changed query, but from your descripton it is not so obvious what are joining fields, for example what is  `z.fk_osebje`

Comment: yeah it is d.fk_personnel, I had to translate tables and accidentally left out that